UK license conversion to German
I entered Germany on October 14, 2023, and my UK license was issued on April 9, 2024, that is after I entered Germany.
However, the 185 day rule states that I take up habitual residence in Germany when I live here for at least 185 days a year.
Therefore, my UK license was issued before 185 day rule which means my license was issued before I took habitual residence in Germany.
So should there be a problem if I convert it?

Were you resident in the UK when the licence was issued?

That sounds like a tax rule, which doesn't necessarily have any bearing on driver licensing.

@Traveller Yes I was a resident. I was there as a student now I moved to Germany also as a student. The confusion I have is that my UK license issue date is after I did my City registeration in Germany. Therefore, will this be an issue to convert my license?

@phoog That is not specifically a tax rule. The 185 day rule is a standard rule for residence. Even if I live in Germany for 184 days, I do not take up residence in Germany. You can check this on German authorities website. There is a document mentioning all these rules for converting license. However, I have heard on some online platforms, issue date of my UK license must be older than my first City registration but according to the document by German authorities my license should be issued before I take up residence in Germany specifically mentioning 185 days.

I see what you mean; the 185-day period is mentioned explicitly in the driver licensing regulations, which certainly disposes of any thought that it might not apply to driver licensing.  Reading the licensing regulations, it is apparent that the actual rule is more nuanced, but it is not surprising that the default position is to take the 185-day threshold strictly.  As far as I can tell, though, the best way to find out whether you can convert your license is just to try to convert it.  The worst that can happen is that they refuse.  Have I missed something?
